# RequestMapping and Hibernate doesn't work as expected after I change the project structure

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am learning the Spring framework for Java EE.

Recently, I'd like to build a restful service with a backend database support as the data source. I have searched a lot of posts about how to and finally find a worked sample project [here](http://christoph-burmeister.eu/?p=2849). This post is great and I had followed his code and made a running application.

But after that, I decide to have my own project structure which is a little bit more clear since I will have more than 5 models and multiple other interfaces.

This is his project structure.

```
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── eu
│   │   │       └── christophburmeister
│   │   │           └── playground
│   │   │               ├── Application.java
│   │   │               ├── IMovieRepository.java
│   │   │               ├── RestServiceController.java
│   │   │               └── models
│   │   │                   ├── Movie.java
│   │   │                   └── Stock.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.properties
│   │       └── log4j2.xml
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       └── resources
```

This is mine.

```
├── README.md
├── pom.xml
├── q_image
│   ├── his.png
│   └── mine.png
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   ├── application
│   │   │   │   └── Application.java
│   │   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   │   └── RestServiceController.java
│   │   │   ├── models
│   │   │   │   └── Stock.java
│   │   │   └── repositories
│   │   │       └── IStockRepository.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.properties
│   │       └── log4j2.xml
```

I checked both application(his and mine) and his version worked but mine didn't. There are configuration/property files but all of them are same and not include any file path configuration.

This is the result in the console for his application. I already know which parts are different from mine, but I have no idea how to solve it. Sorry the log is very long but I will tell you about lines which are different.

They are rows start from `15:09:58.364` to `15:09:58.371`. It looks my hibernate didn't map the table with my model in my DB. I don't have these rows.

And the 4 rows start with `15:09:59.013`. It looks like the URLs are not mapped properly. I don't have these rows.

And the rest of logs are almost same.

```
15:09:52.331 [main] INFO  eu.christophburmeister.playground.Application - entered application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.1.RELEASE)

15:09:52.960 [main] INFO  eu.christophburmeister.playground.Application - Starting Application on Jis-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 3216 (/Users/Kulbear/Documents/workspace/springboot-rest/target/classes started by Kulbear in /Users/Kulbear/Documents/workspace/springboot-rest)
15:09:52.960 [main] INFO  eu.christophburmeister.playground.Application - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
15:09:53.057 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@15eb5ee5: startup date [Mon Aug 15 15:09:53 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
15:09:53.337 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.2.Final
15:09:54.179 [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
15:09:54.801 [main] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe0bb32b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
15:09:55.379 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
15:09:55.398 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service Tomcat
15:09:55.402 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
15:09:55.532 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
15:09:55.532 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2479 ms
15:09:55.918 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
15:09:55.925 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
15:09:55.926 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
15:09:55.926 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
15:09:55.926 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
15:09:56.360 [main] INFO  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
15:09:56.388 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
15:09:56.552 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
15:09:56.554 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
15:09:56.557 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
15:09:56.921 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Mon Aug 15 15:09:57 CST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Aug 15 15:09:57 CST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Aug 15 15:09:57 CST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Aug 15 15:09:57 CST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Aug 15 15:09:57 CST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Aug 15 15:09:57 CST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Aug 15 15:09:57 CST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Aug 15 15:09:57 CST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Aug 15 15:09:57 CST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Aug 15 15:09:57 CST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
15:09:57.700 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
15:09:57.907 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
15:09:58.340 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
15:09:58.340 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
15:09:58.342 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000396: Updating schema
15:09:58.364 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata - HHH000261: Table found: playground.movie
15:09:58.364 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata - HHH000037: Columns: [year, id, title]
15:09:58.364 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata - HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
15:09:58.364 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata - HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
15:09:58.371 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata - HHH000261: Table found: playground.stock
15:09:58.371 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata - HHH000037: Columns: [year, name, id, title]
15:09:58.371 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata - HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
15:09:58.371 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata - HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
15:09:58.372 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000232: Schema update complete
15:09:58.913 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@15eb5ee5: startup date [Mon Aug 15 15:09:53 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
15:09:59.012 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/movies/create]}" onto public java.lang.String eu.christophburmeister.playground.RestServiceController.createMovie(java.lang.String,int)
15:09:59.013 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/movies/update]}" onto public java.lang.String eu.christophburmeister.playground.RestServiceController.readMovie(long,java.lang.String,int)
15:09:59.013 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/movies/read]}" onto public java.lang.String eu.christophburmeister.playground.RestServiceController.readMovie(long)
15:09:59.013 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/movies/delete]}" onto public java.lang.String eu.christophburmeister.playground.RestServiceController.deleteMovie(long)
15:09:59.013 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/movies/readAllBeforeYear]}" onto public java.util.List<eu.christophburmeister.playground.models.Movie> eu.christophburmeister.playground.RestServiceController.getMoviesBeforeYear(int)
15:09:59.015 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
15:09:59.016 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
15:09:59.046 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
15:09:59.046 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
15:09:59.087 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
15:09:59.372 [main] INFO  org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
15:09:59.410 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15:09:59.421 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15:09:59.446 [main] INFO  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool - Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
15:09:59.465 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
15:09:59.471 [main] INFO  eu.christophburmeister.playground.Application - Started Application in 7.008 seconds (JVM running for 8.175)
```

Just for a clear reference my code in my controller looks like below, the only changed part is `movie` to `stock`.

```
package controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import models.Stock;
import repositories.IStockRepository;

@RestController
public class RestServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private IStockRepository repo;

    static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RestServiceController.class.getName());

    // CREATE
    @RequestMapping("/stocks/create")
    @ResponseBody
    public String createStock(String name) {
        Stock stock = new Stock(name);
        try {
            repo.save(stock);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        return "Creation successful: " + String.valueOf(stock.getId());
    }
}
```

I tried `http://localhost:8080/stocks/create?name=abc` and it says

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 15 14:44:27 CST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

My project is at [here](https://github.com/Kulbear/StockRest/tree/master/src/main).

This is a problem with a very long description and error report. Thanks for any help and your time.

Edit:
Here is the `pom.xml` if you think it will be helpful. But the only different part is the `groupId` and `artifactId`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sczq.portfolio</groupId>
    <artifactId>sczq-portfolio</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- we want to rely on external log4j2 -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Application.java` is the main entrance for a spring boot application, which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. That annotation applies many other configurations automatically, like the base package for your controllers, repositories, entities, etc.

In the example application, all classes (repositories, entities, controllers, etc) were either in the same or a sub-directory of `Application.java`, and that helped in configuring the application correctly. Now since you have moved `Application.java` to an independent package, the controllers, repositories, etc are not scanned anymore as they are not visible to `Application.java`.

You need to either configure them manually, using annotations on `Application.java` or restructure your project so that everything else is either directly in, or in a sub-directory, of `Application.java`.

Usually, I prefer keeping `Application.java` in default package. That makes life much easier.

Comment: Hi! Now I have all my other *.java in the sub-packages, but it still doesn't work. Would you please show some tips about how to use annotations on `Application.java` to configure my project structure in the post?

Comment: I moved every file except the model to the default package and now it works (just like his project). Though I still want to know how to manage the project with more complex structure. Thx!

Comment: Move only the 'Application.java` in default package, and keep all other wherever you want.